# Inconsistent output format from Azure GPT Chat API

Tags: azure, chatgpt-api, large-language-model

I have a gpt model deployed in my Azure. I'm making calls to it with a list of line item descriptions and asking the GPT to identify generic line item names. My prompt is as below and I'm passing about 20 item names at a time.
Ex: Pure Protein Bar  Choco, Medium Storage Trays W, Large Storage Trays, Storage, Miscellaneous, Misc line item, Green Bananas etc.

I want to identify generic or non descriptive item names as Misc, miscellaneous etc

My python code and prompt is as below

```
question = """
            In the table below which of the line item descriptons seem too generic? For example Miscellaneous, Parts, Product, Item, Transportation, Business Service, etc\
            Say 0 If no generic line item description is found in the table\
            Otherwise answer with generic line item description seperated with | \
            Please do not provide any additional comments \
            ---Table--- \
        """
descriptions =  "item_descriptions" + '\n' + '\n'.join(df['desc'])
prompt = question + "\n" + descriptions

model = AzureChatOpenAI(
    openai_api_base=openai_base,
    openai_api_version=openai_version,
    deployment_name=dep_name,
    openai_api_key= api_key,
    openai_api_type= api_type,
)

gpt_model = model(
    [
        HumanMessage(content=prompt)
    ])
    
    #fetch reponse
    response = gpt_model.content
    print("This is response: ", response)
```

I have two issues:

1. The output of the response is not always consistent, the model sends additional comments with the response ex: Generic line item description: None found (Answer: 0)
2. The quality of response is not good at times.
   Ex: The model seems to think "Pure Protein Bar" as a generic description.

How can I fix this issue, appreciate any guidance!?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as a generative model, the response is one that can't be determined but with some tricks, you should be able to come fairly close.

What you are trying is called Zero Shot Classification (though you have a few vague examples) and as such depends heavily on the Prompt. The current prompt you have is likely not adequate to guide the model to your definition of "generic".

Check out the [docs for Prompt Engineering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/concepts/advanced-prompt-engineering?pivots=programming-language-chat-completions) to improve your system message and additionally, try including a few more detailed examples. This approach is called Few Shot Classification.

Also, you could try playing with the `temperature` and `top_p` values to reduce the "creativeness" of the model to ensure more consistent responses.

Finally, *after* you experiment with the above *and* have a working solution, you could explore [fine-tuning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/concepts/fine-tuning-considerations) to improve your solution and reduce the number of tokens required for each response.

Do note that fine-tuned models are more expensive since they are charged for hosting as well as tokens processed, so ensure you compare overall costs for your expected volume of requests.